# Can't deploy a xslt webpart as expected

Tags: list-view, feature, web-part-page

In one of my custom list schema, I have defined a custom view :

```
  <View             Type="HTML"
                    DisplayName="My wonderful view"
                    BaseViewID="2"
                    WebPartZoneID="Main"
                    DefaultView="FALSE"
                    TabularView="FALSE"
                    MobileView="TRUE"
                    MobileDefaultView="FALSE"
                    SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx"
                    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png"
                    Url="wonderful.aspx">
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Created"
                  Ascending="FALSE" />
      </OrderBy>
      <GroupBy></GroupBy>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" />
      <FieldRef Name="HistoryEntryType" />
      <FieldRef Name="Field2" />
      <FieldRef Name="Field3" />
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Aggregations Value="Off" />
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <ViewStyle ID="16"/>
  </View>
```

The view definition looks like OK as I can see the view properly when I navigate to the list.

In another feature, I provision a webpart page file, with an xslt view web part to this list and this view :

```
  <AllUsersWebPart ID="viewHistoryWebPart"  
                   WebPartOrder="1"
                   WebPartZoneID="RightColumn"
       >
    <![CDATA[<webParts>
      <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
        <metaData>
          <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          <importErrorMessage>$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;</importErrorMessage>
        </metaData>
        <data>
          <properties>
            <property name="Title" type="string">My history</property>
            <property name="Description" type="string">My WebPart</property>
            <property name="ListUrl" type="string">Lists/mylist</property>
            <property name="BaseViewID" type="int">2</property>
          </properties>
        </data>
      </webPart>
    </webParts>]]>
  </AllUsersWebPart>
```

Unfortunately, when I run deploy the web part page the web part is displaying another view (the view with BaseType=0)

What am I making wrong?

PS: I don't want to use the `<View>` node in place of the `<AllUserWebPart>` because I'm also provisionning a Web Part connection, which is not working with `<View>`

**[Edit]**, I've tested with `<View>` instead of `<AllUsersWebPart>`. This works, the correct view is applied. That let me think there is a problem with my xsltviewwebpart declaration.

Comment: Do all the views in your List have unique BaseViewIDs?

Comment: yes,           each view has a unique baseviewid